# Binding command in viewmodel to menuitem and short cut key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I'm building a small WPF application using MVVM Light, and this is my first application using this framework.

I've got a number of commands in my `MainViewModel`:

```
public RelayCommand NewCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand OpenCommand { get; private set; }
// etc.

public MainViewModel() {
    NewCommand = new RelayCommand( CreateNewFile, CanCreateNewFile );
    OpenCommand = new RelayCommand( OpenFile, CanOpenFile);
    // etc.
}
```

In my XAML, I have a menu:

```
<DocPanel>
    <Menu Name="MainMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" />
            <!-- etc. -->
        </MenuItem>
    <Menu>
</DocPanel>
```

All well and good. But how do I bind these commands to the usual keyboard shortcuts, like Ctrl-N for the new command and Ctrl-O for the open command, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add an InputBinding to Window's InputBindings .

```
private MainViewModel m_ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = m_ViewModel;

    var keyGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control);
    var keyBinding = new KeyBinding(m_ViewModel.NewCommand, keyGesture);
    this.InputBindings.Add(keyBinding);
}
```